# python AWS parameters from parameter store using get_parameters_by_path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am able to get the AWS accessKey, secretKey , SessionToken and secret key info

```
        accessKey = str(assumedRoleObject['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'])
        secretKey = str(assumedRoleObject['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'])
        SessionToken = str(assumedRoleObject['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

Looks like we are getting these temporary values  -->  the temporary accessKey , secretKey , SessionToken

```
store = EC2ParameterStore(
    aws_access_key_id=accessKey ,
    aws_secret_access_key=secretKey ,
    aws_session_token=SessionToken ,  # optional
    region_name='us-west-2'
)
```

Can you pls let me know how I can get the parameters from AWS parameter store with Python using

```
get_parameters_by_path ?
```

I tried this

```
        try:
            secretParams = store.get_parameters_by_path('/dev/', strip_path=False, recursive=True)
        except:
            print("getAWSsecrets: Could not find parameter")
            return "FAIL"
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch parameters that start with path `/dev/`? What was returned by the snippet that you tried?

Comment: so I have a try and except. I just get --> getAWSsecrets: Could not find parameter

Comment: Do you have parameters in SSM with path starting with `/dev/`?

Comment: That was the problem, I had the path incorrectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but maybe this link can help anyone facing an issue like this:

I create a lib to handle such scenarios in an easy way:

[AWStanding](https://github.com/jiss2891/awstanding)